# How to read files from a network drive in php?

Tags: php, scandir, network-drive

I am working on php code as shown below in which I want  to read a network drives as shown below :

[image]

```
$src_dir = is_dir("\\\\ADMPC02-02\\music\\incoming_folder\\");    // Line#A

var_dump($src_dir);  // bool(false)

$mp4_files = preg_grep('~\.(mp4)$~', scandir($src_dir));

$xml_files = preg_grep('~\.(xml)$~', scandir($src_dir));

print_r($mp4_files);  // it doesn't print anything

print_r($xml_files);  // it doesnt print anything
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at Line#A so that I am successfully able network directory. On doing 
`var_dump($src_dir);` it prints `bool(false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works for me:**

```
<?php

$src_dir = '\\\ADMPC02-02\test';
$is_dir = is_dir($src_dir); // returns true
$mp4_files = preg_grep('~\.(mp4)$~', scandir($src_dir));
$xml_files = preg_grep('~\.(xml)$~', scandir($src_dir));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($mp4_files); // lists all the mp4 files in my 'test' folder
print_r($xml_files); // lists all the xml files in my 'test' folder
```

You should also make sure that:

1. [Network discovery](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/support-software/How-to-enable-Network-Discovery-and-configure-sharing-options-in-Windows-10-1008/) is On
2. [Files and printers sharing](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/support-software/How-to-enable-Network-Discovery-and-configure-sharing-options-in-Windows-10-1008/) is On
3. Your *music* folder is publicly shared will all required permissions for the current Windows user running PHP

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying with your code. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: I can see you used three \ operators `\\\ADMPC02-02\test`. Is it right ?

Comment: I added `var_dump($is_dir);`  and its returning `bool(false)`

Comment: I added it too and this is what I'm getting: `bool(true)
Array
(
    [3] => b.mp4
)
Array
(
    [2] => a.xml
)`. I think your issue is coming from the fact PHP/Apache don't have access to this shared folder. Make sure they have read permissions.

Comment: Read permissions to the `music folder` in my code above ?

Comment: Yes, both access to the drive + permissions on this specific folder

Comment: For some reasons, I am unable to turn on network discovery but Files and Printer Sharing is on. Will that make any effect ?

Comment: I think you need both

Comment: For some reasons, I can't turn on network discovery. Some firewall issues probably.

Comment: `$src_dir = '\\\IADMPC02-02\test'; 

$is_dir = is_dir($src_dir); 

var_dump($is_dir); // it returns true`

I am getting true till last line and after that I am getting false.

Comment: Yes you will definitely get `false` if PHP can't access this folder under Windows file sharing permissions. Let's move this conversation to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194028/discussion-between-bruno-leveque-and-flash).

Comment: I lost my connection again after I restarted the server. I am wondering if you can look one more time what went wrong. Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out what is the reason now.